# What is the best way to return an entity with EF5.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I write this little part of code

```
            var query = from u in context.Users
                        join ui in context.UserIdentifiers on u.id equals ui.user_fk
                        where ui.identifier_value == identifier
                        select new User = u;
```

This code is wrong because of the last line `select new User = u;`

So I wrote this

```
            var query = from u in context.Users
                        join ui in context.UserIdentifiers on u.id equals ui.user_fk
                        where ui.identifier_value == identifier
                        select new User
                        {
                            id = u.id,
                            first_name = u.first_name,
                            last_name = u.last_name
                        };
            return query.First();
```

I don't like this code because I need to map all my variables manually: `id = u.id, first_name = u.first_name, last_name = u.last_name`. What if I forgot one or I modify my entity and I forget to update this part of code. What if I get an entity with more than 3 variable. I'm looking for a better way to write this. Could you help me?

Comment: Ah yes I prefer to work with Linq than with Lambda.

Comment: Why not replace the 'select new User { ... }' part with 'select u' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `User` is an entity type:

```
var query = from u in context.Users
   join ui in context.UserIdentifiers on u.id equals ui.user_fk
   where ui.identifier_value == identifier
   select u;
return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

If not, then you have to map:

```
select new User
{
   id = u.id,
   first_name = u.first_name,
   last_name = u.last_name
};
```

or use

```
query.ToList().Select(u => new User(u)).FirstOrDefault()
```

and implement a suitable constructor.

Comment: I choose the solution with return query.FirstOrDefault(); This return my entity object u. Thank to polymorphism u is already serializable, crudable, and lotofothestuffable. I don't need to map anything. Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @B413 Why have you created a class User if you just want the Entity Type?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have are the different classes, you select table `Users`, but you work with class `User`.
So if it is possible for you, just use your class `Users`. Then you can select your Entity directly in your query:

```
var query = from u in context.Users
            join ui in context.UserIdentifiers on u.id equals ui.user_fk
            where ui.identifier_value == identifier
            select u;
```

But i also know that this is not always possible, in some projects we have similar issues. There is no integrated possibility to cast your classes automatically.

Nevertheless there is a tool called [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) with which you can cast your classes. For example you can Map two classes together like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Users, User>();
```

The good thig about this is, that you don't have to tell `automapper` which properties to map if they have the same name in both classes.

Then you can just map automatically all properties like this:

```
var user = Mapper.Map<User>(query.First());
```

Comment: Yeah I know the solution with mappers but if you use this kind of class you didn't understood what Object Oriented is because you are not respecting the Dont Repeat Yourself rule of Object Oriented concept.

Comment: There is no other way, because you use two different classes Users and User. There is nothing like an auto mapping for similar properties. Only way for you is to use a mappertool or to use the Entity Type (or to map manually ;-) )